# Getting Table from MySQL as dict with two keys in Python

Tags: python, mysql, spyder, mysql-connector

i got a table in MySQL looking like this:

`ID   FP  VSN  HSN
 1    xxx 1,5  1,8
 2    yyy 1,1  2,1`

Now, I'm trying to retrieve the values from the table in Python and save them in a dict `n[ID,/Column Name/]` using MySQL-Connector

So far I tried unsuccessfully:

```js
mycursor1=conn.cursor(dictionary=True)

query1 = ("SELECT * FROM `result`")

mycursor1.execute(query1)

columns = mycursor1.description

n = {}

for row in mycursor1:
  for c in columns:
    n[row["ID",c[0]] = float(row[c])
    
mycursor1.close
```

The result in this case should look like this:

`n[1,VSN] = 1,5
 n[1,HSN] = 1,8
 n[2,VSN] = 1,1 
 n[2,HSN] = 2,1`

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You have a small syntax mistake, first line: mycursor should be mycursor1

Comment: thanks, just a typo. I had to type it on my own since i dont have internet on the laptop Im programming on. I get a key error as error message btw

Comment: I can't verify my answer, but I noticed that you don't fetch the results after you execute the query, for example: results = mycursor1.fetchall()
 and than the for loop should look: for row in results:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:

```js
mycursor1=conn.cursor(dictionary=True)

query1 = ("SELECT * FROM `result`")

jt = [i[0] for i in mycursor.description]

mycursor1.execute(query1)

columns = mycursor1.description

n = {}

for row in mycursor1:
  for c in jt:
    n[row["ID"],c] = float(row[c])
    
mycursor1.close
```